# How to set default module params in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, module

so i'm trying my hands on writing my very first library module using pure javascript except that i just hit a snag and need a little bit of help.

I'm using Revealing module pattern because of its neatness. In my module i have my default params in an object like this.

```
var defaults = {
   name : 'John Doe',
   age : 'Unspecified,
   height : '5feet'
};
```

And this works splendid, but i have an init function where a user can pass an object with these keys. e.g

```
Module.init({

     name : 'james',
     age : 12
});
```

Now in my code, i try to write a function that returns the values of each of these keys comparing the default values and the initialized one. If the key/value exists initialized, it should return it else use default. I know what i want, but don't know how to check the objects keys just yet.

```
function getValues (defaultObject, initObject){

   //scans the keys and returns the values

}
```

So in code i can do stuff like

```
var options = getValues(defaultObject, initObject);
var name = options.name;
```

This means that name will either be james if specified or john doe if not. Also for height since i didn't set a value, i get the default too

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do to compare both objects keys, and if the new object has a key, then replace the value in the old one. Here's an example:

```
function getValues(defaultObject, initObject) {
  for (var key in initObject) {
    if (initObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      defaultObject[key] = initObject[key];
    }
  }

  return defaults;
}
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Don't forget to accept the answer (for futur references)

Answer (score 0):

See my answer in another thread how to 
[better define function optional default params : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52082835/1422407](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52082835/1422407)

It may help you to redefine function signature, and as result less useless logic in function itself.